# How to ensure uniqueness of annotation parameters in java class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, annotations

I want to define a JAVA annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Field {
   public String name();
}
```

Then I want to unsure fields level uniqueness for this annotation for example I want to disallow this:

```
public class Abc{
@Field(name="annot")
private String field1;
@Field(name="annot")
private String field2;
}
```

Annotation field name is initialised to the same value "annot" for both field1 and field2. I want to disallow this at compile time. How do it do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an annotation processor. Here are a few links to get you started:

- [Processor Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html)
- [Annotation Processing Tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101/)